# Deleting archived folders in outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I use a folders to sort through my email so i create several folders by topic. I also use the autoarchive folders so i end up with a lot of empty folders in my inbox.

Can i delete these folders in the inbox or will this impact my archive?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove those folders without impacting your archive because the items are no longer in the data file you are using.

> Unlike a traditional backup in which a copy is made, archived items
>   are moved to a separate Outlook Data File and set aside to be accessed
>   when needed.

Source - [How to Archive email in Outlook 2010](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2720581)

Comment: Do you move e-mails manually those folders under your inbox, or do you use Rules Wizard. It won't impact your archive, but your rules wizard may be confused if a folder it is expecting is no longer there.